# Swashbuckle version selector doesn't do anything

Tags: swashbuckle

I have Swashbuckle.Core version 5.6 working in my Owin hosted .Net webapi project. I have enabled multiple versions, and I can see the version selector populated with all of my versions.  However, when I select a version, nothing happens. I am NOT injecting any custom javascript or html. I can remove all other swagger config options, and leave just MultipleApiVersions and EnableDiscoveryUrlSelector. If I turn off the selector, I can manually type in my different version docs and see them just fine. It seems changing the selected version in the drop down is not triggering anything.

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, pebkac, I have to change the drop down, then click on the Explore button. Too used to dropdowns that automatically do something when changed.

Comment: That's because they are using an old version of the Swagger-UI the latest will do it automatically